# Ionic 4 scroll not working properly on iOS

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a Ionic 4 Cordova mobile app that works on Android but has some weird scrolling issues on iOS. The ion-content does not scroll (vertical scroll), and strangely, when I open the side menu, the scroll starts working again, and it stops working when I close the side menu. I attach the html of the app component.

I also have no idea where did the problem come from, as it was working fine with Ionic 3.

Here is the app.component.html for the app:

```
  <ion-header class="menu-header menu-title-ios-adapter">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title class="title-small">Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content class="main-menu-bg">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let menuGroup of appMenu; let i = index" class="transparent-bg">
      <ion-list-header *ngIf="menuGroup.name">
        {{menuGroup.name}}
      </ion-list-header>
      <div *ngFor="let p of menuGroup.pages">
        <ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false" class="transparent-bg"
          [ngClass]="isActive(p) ? 'icon-color-3':'icon-color-light'"
          *ngIf="(p.enabled===undefined || p.enabled.value) && ((p.loginRequired && authenticated) || (!p.loginRequired && !authenticated) || (p.loginRequired === undefined))">
          <!-- <ion-item tappable (click)="openPage(p)" class="transparent-bg"> -->
          <ion-item tappable [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="p.url" class="transparent-bg padding-left-s">
            <icon-wrapper class="slot-icon-padding" customClass="normal" slot="start" [icon]="p.icon" [custom]="p.customIcon"></icon-wrapper>
            <ion-label>
              <span class="text-color-gold">{{p.title}}</span>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>
```

Here is the content of a page:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="view-frame" fxLayout="column">
    <div class="scrollbar-y" (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">
      <ion-list class="list-padding">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let leader of board" class="list-item">
          <!-- item -->
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the css in question:

```
.view-frame {
height: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
z-index: 999999999;
}

.scrollbar-y {
overflow-y: auto !important;
overflow-x: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: This can be a lot of things. Are you using hammerjs? swipe gestures? what's your CSS? are you using anything inside main-menu-bg class that prevents bounce / overflow? Please share more of context and your code. Otherwise its real hard to help

Comment: Thank you for your good observations. I am using hammerjs and swipe gestures indeed. I will edit the question to include some more detail.

Comment: On your .scrollbar-y class try (for experiment) setting: touch-action: pan-x !important; Maybe play around with the values from here: https://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/

Comment: The thing is that it's very strange that the page actually scrolls only when there is a modal above it (or sidemenu open). And the modal responds to the tap and scroll too. Also, I am using a google maps plugin and the behavior is similar, the map moves even when there is a modal on top. Also this happens only on iOS.

Comment: It turns out that hammerjs was indeed the problem. I commented the import and now it's working fine. Thank you for pinpointing the issue

Comment: I’m experiencing the same problem and don’t use hammerjs  Im also not able to reproduce it consistently but get it in two different ionic 6 projects on iOS (12 &15)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is cause by trying to have both swipe and scroll gestures enabled. Try removing swipe or try the suggestion on this thread.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10541
From what the actual people who have made this work have said the issue is related to angular. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as soon as I get back to that project

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to use both horizontal swipe (switch page) while not breaking vertical scroll (scrolling through list of items), which was the actual reason I've included Hammer.js in the first place. Sure, it's ok without swipe just that it used to work with Ionic 3.

Comment: I've been struggling on this issue for a week and saw this post today. I've removed `swipeLeft` feature of `Hammer.js` then the vertical scroll worked.